# How to access entered username using selenium in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am automating website filling in Chrome browser using Selenium.

For the first time user will enter username, date of birth manually. Now my requirement is when user opens my application for next time I want to enter the name and D.O.B using code.

Previously I was using Internet Explorer and there I had beforenavigate event which will inform me that user is going navigating to other URL. So I used to read the required fields and save it in my database.

How to do this in Selenium or Chrome driver ?

WebElement.getAttribute('value') can be used to get the value, but how to know that user has entered the values to that field ?

Please help me.

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you saying you want users to manually put in their login info, extract this data using selenium and use it for automated testing? Because it doesn't make sense to have a user enter data in web automation to me.

Comment: Yes for the first time user will enter. I want to save that and  automate the filling of those fields from second login.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use cookies for that?

Comment: As I said I have no idea how to do it in Chrome. It would be better if I get similar event like beforenavigate(). Do you know how to get user entries using cookies ?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as a test requirement at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fill in a login form for users using Selenium. This is impossible. For this I'd recommend cookies. How to do this depends on the language the website is written in. I'd suggest you do some research on how to do this in your applicaton. If you have questions about this you can make a new post here explaining the details of your application and the issue you are facing.

The reason this does not work in Selenium is that you will need to start a Webdriver to use this. When a user navigates to your website it (most likely) won't be doing this using a Webdriver. Especially not one you can access and send commands to.

Comment: I am using vb.net, It is possible to fill login details using sendkeys(). My question is not about that. I asked how to get the details entered by user using selenium and chrome driver.

Comment: @ITresearcher How is the user going to acces the website? The way I see it a user is sitting at home, visits your website using Chrome and enters login details. You won't have access to this browser as it isn't a webdriver that you started.

Comment: @ITresearcher But to answer your question, you can get the value of a textfield using WebElement.getAttribute('value')

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, I am navigating the user to  login page using chrome driver and wait for the user to enter login details. So now how can I know that user is entered username and D.O.B so that I can save it ?